# Convert Excel with Groovy 2.0.2

Tags: excel

I've been trying to convert an excel to be presented like the data below where data1,1 is row 1 and column 1 and data1,2 is row 1 column 2 and so on.

```
["columns":["head1", "head2", "head3", "head4"], "data":[["data1,1", "data1,2", "data1,3","data1,4"], ["data2,1", "data2,2", "data2,3", "data2,4"], ["data3,1", "data3,2", "data3,3", "data3,4"]]]
```

But I can't get the code right in [Groovy 2.0.2](http://groovy.codehaus.org/). Can you give me a helping hand?

Answer (score 0):

You need [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/), look at their [WritableSheet Interface](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/WritableSheet.html) to insert data...